# How can I open new tab when external link is clicked in a android browser

Tags: android, android-webview, android-browser

I am developing a new browser for android but when I open an external link from browser it kills the already running session. How can I open the link in a new tab?

Comment: Nobody can help you with your problem as nobody knows how your browser works or how you open an external link from your browser. I wonder why you don't better know what 'your' browser is doing if it is 'your' browser.

Comment: Thank you for analysis @greenapps .

Answer (score 1):

I have searched on internet your problem and found this as a useful solution, try this it should work

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.go.com"));
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("new_window", true); //sets new window
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

I think it may help you out.